# No funciona el SELECT después de un DELETE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp

Hola tengo un problema con mi codigo, es una base de datos simple para un trabajo de la universidad por lo tanto soy un poco nuevo en el lenguaje y tenga algunos errores, tengo una tabla de aproximadamente 35 apersonas en donde por medio de un select muestro toda la tabla, en paralelo tengo otra pagina en donde puedo que eliminar personas de esta tabla ingresando su cuil (inventados), una vez que elimino por ejemplo la persona que se encontraba en la posición 15 con id 15 al volver a la pagina para ver la tabla actualizada solo me muestra la tabla hasta la posición 14 es decir hasta el numero anterior al eliminado anteriormente pero sin embargo cuando ingreso a XAMPP a ver la tabla resulta que puedo ver los 34 registros y se elimino correctamente el numero 15 y en el navegador siguen apareciendo solo 14!, aqui les dejo el codigo que estoy utilizando

Aqui el select

```
<?php
require "conex.php";
$con=conectar();
$query= "SELECT  becados.id_becado,becados.apellido,becados.nombre,becados.cuil,lugar.dir_ofi FROM becados JOIN lugar ON becados.id_lugar = lugar.id_lugar ORDER BY id_becado";
$sql= mysqli_query($con,$query);

?>
```

Esta parte del codigo es la que se encarga de mostrarme la tabla por html

```
  <?php

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['id_becado']  ."</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['apellido'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['nombre'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['cuil'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['dir_ofi'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</tbody>";


            ?>
```

y este es el codigo que uso en la pagina eliminar para eliminar alguna fila de la tabla

```
 <?php
        if (isset($_POST['eliminar'])){

            $borracuil = trim($_POST['cuil']);
            $sql= "DELETE FROM becados WHERE cuil = '$borracuil'";
            $eliminar= mysqli_query($conect,$sql);


        }

        ?>
```

Comment: ¿todos los 'becados' tienen un 'lugar'? si no es así y quieres visualizar todos los becados debes reemplazar el `JOIN` por `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: @f.llanquipichun En teoria todos tienen, ahora probé con LEFT JOIN y aparecieron los que no estaban! pero en la columna lugar de trabajo están vacíos, hay 3 personas que trabajan en tesoreria, al eliminar uno de ellos los otros 2 en la tabla dejan de tener como lugar de trabajo tesorería y al parecer por eso desaparecian ( en xampp siguen teniendo sus respectivos lugares de trabajo )

Comment: Por lo que comentas, el error podría estar en la relación de las tablas. Al parecer la relación podría estar en 'cascada' y por eso al eliminar un 'becado' también se elimina un 'lugar'. Quedaría mas claro si pudieses incluir la estructuras de las tablas.